# Exporting SSL certificate from Juniper SA 2000 to IIS 7

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

Has anyone exported SSL certificate (cert and private key) from a Juniper SA 2000 box and tried to import it to IIS 7 box ?
I have tried to google for ways to export the private key from SA 2000 but haven't got any good links. (IIS 7 requires the cert and key put into a .pfx format to import). But if i can export the private key and also have the cert i can create the pfx using openssl.
Any help regarding this is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't export the certificate with the private. I would suggest to contact your CA provider to reissue your certificate using the new CSR generated from your IIS 7 server. Reissuing of certificate in free of charge if you are a GlobalSign customer or your certificate is issued by GlobalSign.

Reissuing your certificate using the CSR generated from the IIS 7 server will allow you to install the certificate using the PEM certificate format (.crt file)

You may refer to this link: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1226960-install-certificate---internet-information-services-iis-7